# Missing modules when running Jupyter notebook on aws

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Jupyter notebook on a virtual machine on AWS, and I am having issues loading modules. Apparently the notebook doesn't find the modules (see image below), but these are listed if I give the command `!conda list`. Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: have you tried: `import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install `

Comment: Problem solved! Could you explain why the standard solution doesn't work?

Comment: I got the code from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/), I simply had it on a notebook and shared. Hope the link helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link! It solved quite a few mysteries ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import sys 
!{sys.executable} -m pip install <your package>
```

[Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)’s a link that might help you find some more information on how to install python packages in jupyter